# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telethon'

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I have installed telethon using the following code:

```
sudo pip3 install telethon
```

I tried to reinstall it and get the following message:

```
 Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from rsa->telethon) (0.4.5)
```

But when i use it in my code:

```
 from telethon import TelegramClient
```

It shows the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telethon'
```

Where should i look to rectify this error ?

Comment: and how You run Your script ? I mean maybe You got default python2 to run python files ?

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: how do i change that to use pthon3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed. Just like you do `pip3`, you should do `python3` and not `python` alone.